# Draw polygon on click of map using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.draw

Below is my code to draw polygon on map.Using this i am able to draw polygon but on click of map , it is enabling draw handler and on second click I am able to draw polygon.

Expected output - 
On first click On map i want to draw first point on map.

```
map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(-37.7772, 175.2756), zoom: 15 });

    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

     var shapeOptions = {
            color: '#0066FF',
            fillColor: '#0066FF',
            // clickable: false
            weight: 10
     };
    var opt = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {
                color: '#FF0000',
                message: ''
            },
            repeatMode: true,
            shapeOptions: shapeOptions
        }
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: false
    }
};

map.on('click', function(e) {
    new L.Draw.Polygon(map).enable();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting a new polygon edit on *every* click on your map. You should check whether the user is currently drawing or not.

To fix the problem with the two clicks (instead of one) you can pass the `onclick` event's `latlng` property to `L.Draw.Polygon(map).addVertex(latlng)` to draw the first polygon vertex on the first click.

```
var editing = false;
map.on('click', function(e) {
  if(!editing){ // do not start multiple "edit sessions"
    editing = true;
    var polyEdit = new L.Draw.Polygon(map);
    polyEdit.enable();
    polyEdit.addVertex(e.latlng);
  }
});

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  editing = false;
  var type = e.layerType,
      layer = e.layer;
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
})
```

Here's a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/NCXOfUF1NAh66Wq1gWJO?p=preview